# Error when trying to create matrix of matrices with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, valueerror

So, I have 3 matrices let's say a,b,c, which have the following shapes:

```
a: (6, 6)
b: (9, 9) 
c: (6, 9)
```

I want to create the following matrix:

```
d = np.matrix([[a, c], [c.T, b]])
```

But I get the following error and I cannot find the solution:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I am out of ideas and cannot find anything similar on Google.

Comment: are these submatrices?

Comment: Yes, these are 3 independent matrices.

Comment: `np.matrix([[a,c],[c.T, b]],dtype=object)` works - if that's what you want.  So does `np.block([[a,c],[c.T, b]])`, but makes something quite different.  And `bmat`.

Comment: More on how `numpy` concatenation compares with MATLAB, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604370/concatenate-matrices-vectors-in-python-like-in-matlab